# react-native Can't display value got in my fetch

Tags: react-native, fetch, render, state

I can't display the values ​​retrieved from my fetch to my

This is my code, but I get 'null is not an object' :

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Image, Text, View, TextInput, StatusBar, Button,         
AppRegistry, TouchableHighlight, TouchableOpacity  } from 'react-native';
import AndroidBackButton from 'react-native-android-back-button'
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation'

export default class ComponenFive extends React.Component {

getInfos(){
    fetch('http://172.16.101.183:3000/users', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            requestType: 'infosCompte'
        })
    })            
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((res) => {
            this.setState({username: res.username, nom: res.nom, prenom: res.prenom, lieu: res.lieu, batiment: res.batiment, bureau: res.bureau});
    })
    .done();
}


render() {
    {this.getInfos}
    return ( 
        <View style={{backgroundColor: 'white', flex: 1}}>
            <Text>Identifiant : {this.state.username}</Text>
        </View>
    )
}
```

}

Do you have any idea to help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using fetch you are getting more than just the data on json.

try this example

```
fetch('http://172.16.101.183:3000/users', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            requestType: 'infosCompte'
        })
    })            
    .then(response => response.json().then(json => ({ json, response })))
    .then(({ json, response }) => {
        if (!response.ok) {
            return Promise.reject(json);
        }
        return json;
    })  
    .then((res) => {
            this.setState({username: res.username, nom: res.nom, prenom: res.prenom, lieu: res.lieu, batiment: res.batiment, bureau: res.bureau});
    })
    .done();
```

UPDATE:

Sorry just seen your code and is not correct. Using {this.getInfos} on render() is wrong. getInfo is just a function. You dont return anything. If you want to call this function as it is use **componentWillMount** and set the state on constructor

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {username: '', nom: ''};
}
componentWillMount() {
    this.getInfos()
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I still have the same error message

Comment: Oh I didn't know that ! Thanks a lot it's working now !

Answer (score 0):

res already json. pull the data directly from the res.

```
console.log(res);
let resData = JSON.parse(res._bodyText);
this.setState({username: resData.username, nom: resData.nom, .....})
```